# What are "ordered functions"?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

In the [solution to Problem 156b at p.120](https://github.com/OpenDiscreteMath/ibl-combinatorics/blob/update-bogart/ComboNoteswSolutions11-6-04.pdf) of Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery by Kenneth P. Bogart:
$\newcommand{\risefac}[2]{{#1}^{\overline{#2}}}$

> $\risefac{n}{k}$ counts the number of ordered functions from a $k$-element set to an $n$-element set.

What are "ordered functions" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at (the obvious place):

https://bogart.openmathbooks.org/ctgd/s3-1-distrib-idea.html

> More precisely, an ordered function from a set $S$ to a set $T$ is a function that assigns an (ordered) list of elements of $S$ to some, but not necessarily all, elements of $T$ in such a way that each element of $S$
> appears on one and only one of the lists.

...

> The phrase ordered function is not a standard one, because there is as yet no standard name for the result of an ordered distribution problem.